# Trouble changing background color of row in codename one table

Tags: background-color, codenameone

I have an app with a route datatable. The data is csv file. I like
highlight a row in a table in codenameone by changing the backgroundcolor of the row. How can I do this?

My Code is

```
        String File_Name ="/route.csv";
        //"/root/sdcard/Pictures/route.csv";
        File f= new File (File_Name);
        if (f.exists())

        InputStream is = Display.getInstance().getResourceAsStream(getClass(), File_Name );
        CSVParser parser = new CSVParser();
        String[][] data = parser.parse(is);
        String[] columnNames = new String[data[0].length];


        l =  data.length;
        for(int iter=  0 ; iter < columnNames.length ; iter++) {

        if (iter== 0) {
         columnNames[iter] = "Naam";
        } 
        else if (iter== 1) {
         columnNames[iter] = "Latitude";
        } 
         else if (iter== 2) {
          columnNames[iter] = "Longitude";
         } 
        } 
     tm = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, data);    

        }
    }
    catch (IOException err){
         err.printStackTrace();
    }
```

further in the code

```
 Table tm2 = new Table(tm)
```

**EDIT solved myself**
I edited the table definiton tm2  and added the variable A. A is the row which is  highlighted

```
  Table tm2 = new Table(tm)  {
@Override
public Component createCell(Object value, int row, int column, boolean editable) { // (1)

    Component cell;

    cell = super.createCell(value, row, column, editable);


    if(row > a-1 && row < a+1) { // (5)
        // pinstripe effect 
        cell.getAllStyles().setBgColor(0xe2f30d);
        cell.getAllStyles().setBgTransparency(255);
    }
    return cell;

}
```

Comment: You need to say what language this is and for what platform. Also please put the answer into the answer box, and not into the question. You are permitted to answer your own question and then accept that answer.

Comment: @BrianTompsett-汤莱恩 he is referring to [Codename One](https://www.codenameone.com/) (not sure if the tag was there when you commented) since Codename One is Java based the language is implied

Answer (score 0):

Changing the cell color is discussed in [the developer guide](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/components.html) as you probably discovered the pinstripe sample from there.

The full sample from the developer guide is this:

```
Table table = new Table(model) {
    @Override
    protected Component createCell(Object value, int row, int column, boolean editable) { 
        Component cell;
        if(row == 1 && column == 1) {  
            Picker p = new Picker();
            p.setType(Display.PICKER_TYPE_STRINGS);
            p.setStrings("Row B can now stretch", "This is a good value", "So Is This", "Better than text field");
            p.setSelectedString((String)value);  
            p.setUIID("TableCell");
            p.addActionListener((e) -> getModel().setValueAt(row, column, p.getSelectedString()));  
            cell = p;
        } else {
            cell = super.createCell(value, row, column, editable);
        }
        if(row > -1 && row % 2 == 0) {  
            // pinstripe effect
            cell.getAllStyles().setBgColor(0xeeeeee);
            cell.getAllStyles().setBgTransparency(255);
        }
        return cell;
    }

    @Override
    protected TableLayout.Constraint createCellConstraint(Object value, int row, int column) {
        TableLayout.Constraint con =  super.createCellConstraint(value, row, column);
        if(row == 1 && column == 1) {
            con.setHorizontalSpan(2);
        }
        con.setWidthPercentage(33);
        return con;
    }
};
```

[image]